# Discord.py Never proceeds to ready

Tags: python, discord.py, python-asyncio

I am rewriting my discord bot wrapper to update it and make it more asynchronous, its been almost two years since I made it,  I am using discord.py 2.0.0 I was using 1.6 i believe.

My main file  is Helix.py:

```
"""
    asynchronous Helix Bot Wrapper class
"""

###   Imports   ###
import os
import colorlog
import datetime
import discord
import sys
import helix_bot.bot.utility.config as cfg
import logging
from datetime import datetime
from discord.ext import commands
from sqlalchemy_utils import database_exists, create_database

## Logging set up and format with colorlog
log = logging.getLogger("HELIX_BOT")

# Change recursion limit to avoid errors
sys.setrecursionlimit(100000)


###   HELIX BOT CLASS   ###
class Helix(commands.AutoShardedBot):
    def __init__(self, config=None):
        # Set config
        self.aio_session = None
        if config is None:
            config = cfg.ConfigDefaults.Config_file

        self.description = """
        Helix - A Custom Bot for SinLess Games Official Discord Server and more!
        """

        self.config = cfg.Config(config)

        #####################################
        ###   SETUP VARIABLES FOR HELIX   ###
        #####################################

        ### GENERAL VARIABLES ###
        self.Version = self.config.version
        self.owner_id = self.config.owner_id
        self.owner = self.config.owner

        ### DISCORD VARIABLES ###
        self.TOKEN = self.config.login_token
        self.applicationID = self.config.applicationID
        self.invite_url = self.config.InviteURL
        self.PublicKey = self.config.PublicKey
        self.ClientID = self.config.ClientID
        self.ClientSecret = self.config.ClientSecret
        self.Prefix = self.config.prefix

        ###   SQL VARIABLES   ###
        self.sql_host = self.config.sql_host
        self.sql_user = self.config.sql_user
        self.sql_pass = self.config.sql_passwd
        self.sql_ddb = self.config.sql_ddb
        self.Model_Version = self.config.model_version
        self.db_connect = f'mysql+pymysql://{self.sql_user}:{self.sql_pass}@{self.sql_host}/{self.sql_ddb}'

        ###   DEBUG VARIABLES   ###
        self.debug_level = self.config.debug_level
        self.show_config = self.config.Show_Config
        self.log_channel = self.config.Log_Channel

        ###   SPOTIFY VARIABLES   ###
        self.spotify_client_id = self.config.spotify_client_id
        self.spotify_client_secret = self.config.spotify_client_secret

        ### PERMISSIONS ###
        self.dev_ids = self.config.devids
        self.bot_exception_ids = self.config.bot_exception_ids

        ########################
        ### LOGGING SETTINGS ###
        ########################

        ### SET LOG LEVEL ###
        self.debug_level = 'DEBUG'
        log.setLevel(self.debug_level)
        self.log_file = 'logs/helix.log'

        ### CREATE HANDLER ###
        self.helix_h = logging.FileHandler(self.log_file)
        self.helix_h.setLevel(self.debug_level)

        ### CONSOLE HANDLER ###
        CH = logging.StreamHandler()
        CH.setLevel(self.debug_level)

        ### FORMATTER ###
        self.formatter = colorlog.ColoredFormatter(
            "%(log_color)s[%(asctime)s] [%(levelname)s] %(message)s",
            datefmt=None,
            reset=True,
            log_colors={
                'DEBUG': 'cyan',
                'INFO': 'green',
                'WARNING': 'yellow',
                'ERROR': 'red',
                'CRITICAL': 'bold_red',

                'EVERYTHING': 'white',
                'NOISY': 'white',
                'FFMPEG': 'bold_purple',
                'VOICEDEBUG': 'purple',
            },
            secondary_log_colors={},
            style='%'
        )
        self.helix_h.setFormatter(self.formatter)
        CH.setFormatter(self.formatter)
        log.addHandler(self.helix_h)
        log.addHandler(CH)
        log.info("Logging set up")

        intents = discord.Intents.all()
        log.info("Intents set up")
        log.debug("Intents: {}".format(intents))

        ###   LOAD BOT   ###
        super().__init__(
            command_prefix=self.Prefix,
            intents=intents,
            description=self.description,
            case_insensitive=True,
            start_time=datetime.utcnow(),
        )
        ###   Remove help command   ###
        super().remove_command('help')

        ###   Build Database   ###
        self.build_database()

    def build_database(self):
        if not database_exists(self.db_connect):
            log.info("Creating database...")
            create_database(self.db_connect)
            log.info("Database created")
        else:
            log.info("Database already exists")

    ### RUN Helix Bot Async ###
    async def run(self, **kwargs):
        log.info("Starting Helix...")
        try:
            await self.login(self.TOKEN)
        except Exception as e:
            log.error(f'{type(e).__name__} - {e}')
        log.info("Helix Logged in as {}#{}".format(self.user.name, self.user.discriminator))
        log.info("Waiting {}#{} for  to be Ready...".format(self.user.name, self.user.discriminator))
        try:
            await self.wait_until_ready()
        except Exception as e:
            log.error(f'{type(e).__name__} - {e}')
        log.info("{}#{} is ready".format(self.user.name, self.user.discriminator))
        try:
            await self.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="Helix"))
        except Exception as e:
            log.error(f'{type(e).__name__} - {e}')
        log.info("{}#{} is ready!".format(self.user.name, self.user.discriminator))
        try:
            await self.load_extensions()
        except Exception as e:
            log.error(f'{type(e).__name__} - {e}')
        log.info("{}#{}is loaded!".format(self.user.name, self.user.discriminator))

    ###   LOAD_EXTENSIONS Async   ###
    async def load_extensions(self):
        for filename in os.listdir('./bot/cogs'):
            if filename.endswith('.py'):
                log.info("Loading {}...".format(filename))
                self.load_extension(f'bot.cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
            log.info("Loaded Cog {}".format(filename))

    ###   command to unload a cog   ###
    @commands.command(name='unload', aliases=['unload_cog'])
    @commands.is_owner()
    async def unload_cog(self, ctx, *, cog: str):
        """Unloads a cog"""
        try:
            await self.unload_extension(cog)
            await ctx.send(f'Unloaded {cog}')
        except Exception as e:
            await ctx.send(f'{type(e).__name__} - {e}')

    ###   command to reload a cog   ###
    @commands.command(name='reload', aliases=['reload_cog'])
    @commands.is_owner()
    async def reload_cog(self, ctx, *, cog: str):
        """Reloads a cog"""
        try:
            await self.unload_extension(cog)
            self.load_extension(cog)
            await ctx.send(f'Reloaded {cog}')
        except Exception as e:
            await ctx.send(f'{type(e).__name__} - {e}')

    ###   LOAD_EXTENSION   ###
    def load_extension(self, extension, **kwargs):
        try:
            self.load_extension(extension)
        except Exception as e:
            log.error(f'{type(e).__name__} - {e}')
```

and the file i use to run it is :

```
import threading
import asyncio
from bot.helix import Helix


async def main():
    bot = Helix()
    await bot.run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    threading.Thread(target=asyncio.run(main())).start()
```

My main question is even after 2 hours of letting it run, it never reaches ready status that last thing it will say is waiting for helix to be ready.

I have looked around and ready that it does take 75% longer to ready, according to the official documentation. But 2 hours and still nor ready. Dis I do something wrong or what is my problem. I have searched through what i could, and as far as i know it should work. Though i will continue to look.

Comment: There is no method `wait_until_ready()` in your class.

Comment: ```wait_until_ready()``` is a couroutine of discord.py Which can be found here:
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=wait_until_ready#discord.Client.wait_until_ready

Comment: Please include a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

The client will never properly become ready because you need to `connect` AND `login`. You can also simply use the `[Client].start` instead.

From the [docs here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=connect#discord.Client.login):

> `await login(token)`
>
> Logs in the client with the specified credentials and calls the `setup_hook()`.
>
> `await connect(*, reconnect=True)`
>
> Creates a websocket connection and lets the websocket listen to messages from Discord. This is a loop that runs the entire event system and miscellaneous aspects of the library. Control is not resumed until the WebSocket connection is terminated.

**Using `start` will properly start the bot.**

> `await start(token, *, reconnect=True)`
>
> A shorthand coroutine for `login()` + `connect()`.